# How to add a rows to an empty matrix using a loop in python?

Tags: python

My try :

```
matrix=[[]]
if my conidtion is filled:
     matrix+=([[val1],[val2],[val3]])
     print matrix
```

where **val1**, **val2**, and **val3** change with each iteration of my if loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list.append`

**Ex:**

```
matrix=[]
if my conidtion is filled:
     matrix.append([val1, val2, val3])
     print matrix
```